How can I manage users on my VPS hosted Flask website
I'm building a website, but I just encountered a problem that I have not been able to solve:
I have a python flask app as well as several HTML files that make up my website, hosted on a VPS
The problem is this: I want visitors of my website to be able to create accounts on my website and I just can't make this work. The idea is to add billing later on for a "premium" plan
How can I make this work?
I need users to be able to create accounts and I need to be able to charge them money. Keep in mind that all of this is running on a Ubuntu VPS and the main code is a Python Flask application
These are some ideas I came up with:

install wordpress on VPS
install wordpress on webspace and have a headless python script, communication via API
use SQLAlchemy in Flask app


Do you have any specific question about this?

@NicoHaase would you think it's better to a) install wordpress on VPS and have my python app on VPS too b) have wordpress installed on webspace and python app on VPS or do you have another idea to make this work?

Please add all clarifications to your question by editing it. I don't see how installing Wordpress on either "VPS" or "webspace" makes a huge difference
